GitLab CI/CD pipeline does not use updated pyproject.toml after version bump
I am using GitLab CI/CD for automating the release process of my Python package, and I've encountered an issue where the release job does not seem to use the updated pyproject.toml file that was modified in the preceding bump_version job. Here's the relevant part of my .gitlab-ci.yml:
bump_version:
  stage: release
  script:
    - *install_poetry
    - poetry version $(git describe --tags)
    - git add pyproject.toml
    - git commit -m "Bump version"
    - git push origin --follow-tags HEAD:${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
  only:
    - tags

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - *install_poetry
    - PROJECT_NAME_SAFE=$(echo "${CI_PROJECT_NAME}" | sed 's/ /-/g')
    - poetry config repositories.$PROJECT_NAME_SAFE https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi
    - poetry publish --repository $PROJECT_NAME_SAFE
      --username gitlab-ci-token
      --password ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
      --build
  only:
    - tags
  needs: [ bump_version ]

In the bump_version job, the version in pyproject.toml is successfully updated and pushed back to the repository. However, when the release job runs, it still uses the old pyproject.toml file prior to the version bump.
Is there something I am missing in the configuration that would ensure the release job fetches the latest commit containing the bumped version in pyproject.toml?

The reason it isn't seeing the new version is that all of the jobs in a pipeline run for the same commit. The bump_version job is making a new commit, which triggers a new pipeline, but that new pipeline will not run the release job because there isn't a tag associated with the second pipeline. I would recommend against bumping the version in CI. When you tag a commit, the tag should correspond to the version already specified in pyproject.toml. Instead, I would add a step in the release script to ensure that, if the tag is a version, the tag matches the pyproject.toml version.
